# Laravel Homestead 12.7 throws repository error at the end of vagrant up

Tags: vagrant, homestead

I am on an Ubuntu machine. I have just cloned the Laravel Homestead v12.7.

At the end of running `vagrant up` I get the following error at then end:

> The repository 'https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x focal Release' no longer has a Release file.
> The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
> assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
> should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
> went wrong.

Then I `ssh` into the machine with `vagrant ssh` and everything seems to look fine. However, the website doesn't show up.

I already have tried `vagrant reload`, `vagrant provision` & `vagrant reload --provision` and I still get that error.

Are there some fixes to let the `vagrant up` process finish properly?

## Solved

THanks to @user3210614, I added the following line to my `Homestead.yaml` file:

```
#####
# ...
databases:
    - homestead

backup: true

in-flight-service: true

# .....
```

And that did the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was struggiling with the same issue on my windows machine and found someone has opened this as an issue on the homestead github:

```
https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/1707
```

There has been a fix released which is to insert the `in-flight-service: true` option inside your `Homestead.yaml` file then `vagrant destroy` and `vagrant up`